# Can't connect to new wifi networks

Tags: networking

For some reason, when I try to connect to new wifi networks, I get the "trying to connect spinning icon" that should take me to the form to type the password but it never does, it keeps spinning and after a few seconds just says that I'm disconnect.

Networks that were already saved, connect automatically without a problem and ethernet works wonderful as well.

Comment: Can you try by adding a new connection? **Edit Connections > Add > Wifi**. Enter all details manually and try if that works

Comment: @Yaksha No, but works if I try to connect to hidden wifi and enter details manually... It's just not very practical

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the **"Hidden Wi-Fi Network"**:

1. Choose **Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...** in the WiFi dropdown menu below the Wi-Fi icon.
2. Leave "Connection" as "New..."
3. Type the exact name of the network
4. Choose the Wi-Fi security type. For example, "WPA & WPA2 Personal" worked in my case (and you might find some indication about it on some connection details printed e.g. on the backside of your router or so)
5. When asked, provide the password.

Voilà, in my case it took a few seconds longer than usual to eventually connect than, but it readily worked.

The connection should readily remain available also after you reboot, without you having to re-add it.

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04. My Wi-Fi Password: - oops, nope.

**Disclaimer**: This is merely a more detailed description of what @Ryuuka solved with his comment already. I found it worth the write-up as I spent hours before without finding an easy solution.